# having this error called "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Good evening programmers. I'm doing my final year project and am doing a food ordering system based on VB.net with Access database. I have this error that keeps on appearing when i debug my application,

**A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

Here's a copy of the code i'm working on. This code is following a similar code which inputs admin's details. This particular code in this form intends to accept the Admin's ID and Password used to login into the system.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class adminadd2

    'must put everytime, global bro
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click

        Dim TA As New CQFOSDataSet1TableAdapters.adminloginTableAdapter
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection


        'Dim yourconnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("yourconnectionstring").ConnectionString

        'con = New OleDbConnection(yourconnection)

        'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Mark1.My.MySettings.CQFOSConnectionString").ConnectionString
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text


        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO adminlogin(Username,Password) VALUES(@Username,@Password)"


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", adminid.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", adminpass.Text)

        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim RowsAffected As Integer
        con.Open()

        'rowaffected returns the number or row affected
        RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim selectQuery As String = "Select FROM adminlogin"
        If RowsAffected = 1 Then
            MsgBox("New Admin is saved. Login Using your credentials.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "CQFOS")
        End If
        con.Close()

        Me.Hide()
        adminaccess.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Plain text passwords make me sad :(

Comment: @joelcoehoorn, i don't get you.

Answer (score 1):

There are first chance exceptions and second chance exceptions; second chance exceptions are the ones that your code attempt to handle, while first chance exceptions are "seen" by the debugger. In other words, first chance exceptions only matter when you are debugging.

Here is some MSDN documentation on [First and second chance exception handling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

`Password` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).  Enclose it in square brackets in your `INSERT` statement.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO adminlogin(Username,[Password]) VALUES(@Username,@Password)"
```

Comment: this works. thanks @hansUp!

but now i'm having a problem. when i debug and run the application, it saves the data in the access database, and i can view the saved data. But a while later, the data is automatically removed from the tables, and i have to input it again. Does anyone have an idea why does this happening?

Comment: I've seen that issue in other SO questions.  Apparently there is a Visual Studio project setting which makes the app use a *copy* of the db file each time, so the data changes don't get saved back to the original db file.  Actually I don't do .Net so can't say more except search previous SO questions, and post a new question if you can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

each time you run the application in the debugger it copies the access database from the project directory to the bin/debug directory thus overwriting the data you previously input whilst debugging.

Set the behaviour of the access dataset to Do Not Copy and your data will persist through debug sessions.